# My Java project creates real vertex or are irreal?

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a little problem with the relation about Java and OrientDB.

First: I connect my ETL with DB created in OrientDB.

Second: I import my CSV data to my Java project.

Third: i can create the vertex and edges for OrientDB in my Java project.

Fourth: I try to introduce the CSV data in the databases vertex and edge

All is ok but when I start the query in OrientDB I cant see the datas.

Where is my problem? Anyone can help me?

Thank in advance.

Here is the code:

```
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.TransactionalGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class csvToOrientdb {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    csvToOrientdb cto = new csvToOrientdb();
    cto.run();
}

public void run() {        

    TransactionalGraph graph = new OrientGraph("plocal:mydb", "admin", "admin");

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String dato = "";
    String csvSplitBy = ";";
    int numDumb = 1;
    int keyNum = 1;

    Vertex Key, DeveloperEmail, CertificatePublicKey, CertificateFingerprint, DeveloperName, CertificateSubjectCommonName;
    Edge relacion1, relacion2, relacion3, relacion4, relacion5, relacion6, relacion7, relacion8, relacion9;

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < numDumb; i++) {
            String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\DANI\\Desktop\\dumps\\dump_" + i;

            try {

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
                while ((dato = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    String[] datos = dato.split(csvSplitBy, 15);

                    Key = graph.addVertex(datos[0]);

                    Key.setProperty("sha256", datos[1]);
                    Key.setProperty("packageName", datos[2]);
                    Key.setProperty("origin", datos[3]);
                    Key.setProperty("versionCode", datos[4]);
                    Key.setProperty("certificateValidityGapRoundedYears", datos[10]);

                    DeveloperEmail = graph.addVertex(datos[5]);

                    DeveloperName = graph.addVertex(datos[6]);
                    DeveloperName.setProperty("developerAddress", datos[13]);
                    DeveloperName.setProperty("developerPrivacy", datos[14]);
                    DeveloperName.setProperty("developerWeb", datos[7]);

                    CertificatePublicKey = graph.addVertex(datos[8]);

                    CertificateFingerprint = graph.addVertex(datos[9]);

                    CertificateSubjectCommonName = graph.addVertex(datos[11]);
                    CertificateSubjectCommonName.setProperty("certificateIssuerCommonName", datos[12]);

                    relacion1 = graph.addEdge(null, CertificateFingerprint, DeveloperEmail, "used_by ");
                    relacion2 = graph.addEdge(null, DeveloperEmail, Key, "developer_of ");
                    relacion3 = graph.addEdge(null, CertificateFingerprint, Key, "sign ");
                    relacion4 = graph.addEdge(null, DeveloperName, DeveloperEmail, "has_email ");
                    relacion5 = graph.addEdge(null, CertificateSubjectCommonName, CertificateFingerprint, "in_cert ");
                    relacion6 = graph.addEdge(null, CertificateSubjectCommonName, CertificatePublicKey, "appears_with ");
                    relacion7 = graph.addEdge(null, CertificatePublicKey, CertificateFingerprint, "in_cert ");
                    relacion8 = graph.addEdge(null, DeveloperEmail, CertificateFingerprint, "sign_with ");
                    relacion9 = graph.addEdge(null, CertificatePublicKey, CertificateSubjectCommonName, "sign_in ");

                    keyNum++;

                    System.out.println("Dumb done numer : " + i + " keys: " + keyNum);

                    graph.commit();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        graph.rollback();
    } finally {
        graph.shutdown();
}
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, could you post the class csvToOrientdb, please? Thx

Comment: Hi, you can see the class csvToOrientDB with the imports etc in the post. public class csvToOrientdb {...}. Anything more? thank u =)

Comment: Maybe my request is unclear, i mean what is declared into csvToOrientdb class, what that class should do etc.. Let me know if it's not clear. Thx in advance

Comment: I need put the CSV data in the DDBB of orientDB. In the first place I connect Java to my DDBB created. I collect in the "String[] datos" all the CSV data. In second place I create the vertex and edges that i need (with the properties) in my DDBB. In the last place I put the datas in the vertex and edges for use this in my DDBB.

Comment: The problem is that the DDBB is empty, why? I did the vertex and edge as the OrientDB doc say. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with this csv

```
Class_0;one;two;three;four;Class_5;Class_6;seven;Class_8;Class_9;ten;Class_11;twelve;thirteen;fourteen
```

and I can see the data.

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey! how did you do this? I can´t see the data. What im doing wrong? I created the DDBB, open the server and run my code. Did you do the same as me?  Thank in advance

Comment: What is the path where did you create DDBB ?

Comment: I create the DB in my desktop, but with plocal it is not enought? Thank u.

Comment: With your code you create the db mydb in the workspace of your project.

If you want to connect to the db DDBB created in your desktop you must use the following code

TransactionalGraph graph = new OrientGraph("plocal:C:\\Users\\DANI\\Desktop\\DDBB", "admin", "admin");

I use these command 
1) I launched the console and created the db DDBBB in the desktop folder.
2) I logged out of the db and I closed the console.
3) I executed your code.
4) I launched the console and connected with the db DDBBB.
5) I executed "select from v" and I saw your data.

Comment: Ok I did it and now I can see the data. Thank u so much!